# Replication of best log pseudolikelihood in Stata

Tags: stata, multinomial, log-likelihood

I am running a multinomial logistic regression in Stata, and have found that the modelling procedure seems to finish before the log pseudolikelihood is completely replicated:

```
Iteration 0: log pseudolikelihood = -144989.44
Iteration 1: log pseudolikelihood = -144138.93
Iteration 2: log pseudolikelihood = -144127.49
Iteration 3: log pseudolikelihood = -144127.48

[regression output]
```

My understanding of Stata was that it keeps doing iterations until the best LL value is replicated? In other programs I would force more iterations to ensure that it's not converged on a local solution, but for Stata I can only find advice on how to set the maximum number of iterations, not the minimum.

Any thoughts on this (how concerned I should be, or any checks I can do) would be most welcome.

Comment: See `help maximize` for options you can use to force more iterations. I don't find this a source of concern in my own work. Here you are concerned about 1 part in 10 million....

Comment: I couldn't find an option to force more iterations in `help maximise`, any chance you can elaborate? I'm probably missing something obvious. As you say though, I likely don't need to be concerned about it.

Comment: The option `ltolerance()` can force more iterations if set low enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to force more iterations until the best LL was replicated by adding the option `ltolerance(0)`, as recommended to me in the comments.